# How to sort an array based on the values of the elements?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

```
A = [125,313,275,120]
B = [277,715,823,450]
```

I have two arrays and I want to sort A and I want to apply the same ordering to B, meaning that I want to have : I know I can use sort (A), I just don't know how to get B1.

```
A1 = [120,125,275,313]
B1 = [450,277,823,715]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
[A1, I] = sort(A);
B1 = B(I);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is listed in Matlab's help page for 'sort'. You can output the sorting indices for A and apply it for B. SO:

```
[A1, ind]=sort(A);
B1=B(ind);
```